# modx with minishop2 view all categories

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

For example i have such structure of my application:

```
document1
document2
DemoCatalog
 Catalog1
 Catalog2
   SubCatalog1
   Subcatalog2
      SubSubCatalog1
 Catalog3
   SubCatalog1
```

How could i view only such structure:

```
 Catalog1
 Catalog2
 Catalog3
```

How could i display such navistructure with Wayfinder? 
if my DemoCatalog id is 6, i try so:

```
 [[Wayfinder? &startId=`6` &level=`0`]]
```

but  it didn't display anything, what i do wrong? and how to solve my problem?

i use modx revo

Comment: Just type `&level=\`1\``

Comment: @Vasis i try, but when i set so, for example if i had in DemoCatalog one product, id display it too, but i need to display only categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i solve this so:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`6` &level=`1` &where=`{"isfolder":"1"}`]]
```